# Cheapest type of Read-Only Memory allowing Random access before Year 1970

Tags: history, memory, rom

Back in the 50s and 60s people had:

- random access, read-write memories like Magnetic Cores.
- sequential access, read-write memories like Delay Lines and Magnetic Tapes.

And:

- sequential access, write once, read-only memories like Punch Card and Perforated Tape, which are not called ROM traditionally.

So what about **random access, read-only** memories which are called ROM now? Which kind of random access, read-only memories,  say Core Rope Memory, Mask ROM, PROM, TROS, CROS..., was cheapest **per kbit** before Year 1970? And which kind has the simplest decoding/addressing mechanism?

*PS:*

- *[Historical price of ROM](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/historical-price-of-rom) talks about solid state ROM, which is totally different a question.*
- *By saying random/sequential, there lies Direct-access storage device (DASD, like Magnetic Drums and Data Cells) in between, which has fixed address and variable access time, while this question talks about ROMs without delay of seeking.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119926/discussion-on-question-by-schezuk-cheapest-type-of-read-only-memory-allowing-ran).

Comment: *"... memories like Punch Card and Perforated Tape"* -- You're (incorrectly) conflating (computer) memory with (nonvolatile) storage media and peripherals.  A CPU instruction that accesses *memory* can complete in one cycle (probably with wait states).  The various peripherals and media (that you incorrectly call *"memory"*) require device drivers using I/O operations.  There simply is no equivalence.

Answer (score 7):

The question seams to imply that there was a need for a ROM in the same sense as it was used in the 1970s and 80s, but why wasting address space and money on storage that could only be used for one purpose?

Machines, way passed the mentioned cut of date of 1970, used magnetic media (drums) and magnetic core for RAM. Both are persistent storage, this means information stored there will be present even after a power cycle. All a CPU needed to do is starting to operate from that memory. Data processing and scientific computing relied on having RAM for changing tasks, while process automation as well was happy with loading core once a while and after that simply used it ROM like - some machines had even ways to switch of writing of (new) data, essentially turning core into ROM.

Long story short: **Prior to the 1970s there was no need for ROMs in the sense we know today**.

Applications of ROM like storage was, if at all, needed in micro program storage, but solutions here were rather specific to each CPU manufacturer and machine, like [CCROS](https://www.computerhistory.org/revolution/mainframe-computers/7/164/578), [TROS](http://www.righto.com/2019/11/tros-how-ibm-mainframes-stored.html) and similar (*1,*2). Also, noone really wanted ROMS. In fact, this is  the very reason why IBM developed the floppy drive: to load the microcode from a persistent media to micro code storage. That way they could use RAM,but kept the content static - and change it when needed.

All ROM like solutions of the time were special to type and hand made.

ROMs as we know now grew out of decoders. Fixed function devices translating information - like turning a key press into ASCII. A job that for early terminals was done literally with piles of diodes (*3). But even this use did only come up after 1970. As only then the need for high volume production, i.e. more than a few dozend, became a thing.

> was cheapest per kbit before Year 1970?

Since there were no common, interchangeable solution before 1970, but only partitial solutions specific to each device, comparable prices can not be given.

---

*1 - I remember a TROSS like system using modified punch cards instead of special mylar sheets. While not as dense, they had the advantage that ROM content could created by using a standard key punch. Thus patching a ROM was simply DUPing the card until the change, enter the new value and DUPing again until the card was done. ROM changes within minutes, needing only equipment available in any computing center - beside the special cards that is. Even more, a new ROM stack could be delivered as tape and outputted by using a standard card punch.

Depending on one's POV, this may qualify as 'cheapest', still, it's a low volume hand made thing.

*2 - [Core Rope Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_rope_memory) was as well a very specific niche solution

*3 - I remember that in 1977 I got hold of two scrapped terminal keyboards, which served as my main source for diodes for several years, as every key was connected to a row of 0..7  diodes to encode its ASCII value.

Comment: Core memory, sure, but I'm curious -- which machine was still using drum memory after 1970?

Comment: @MichaelGraf You mean beside the fact that the question is about _before_ 1970? Quite some. Beside that drums were still a thing for the big guys, even new machines like the PDP-11, introduced in 1970, were delivered with drums. Most notably an 11/45 in 1974 to UC Berkeley with core memory and a drum. There's a reason that the 1977 introduced BSD Unix  uses /dev/drum for swap. Disks were simply slower. A typical 70s drum had a average access time of 8 µs - about 8-10 times faster than any disk drive. Drums were a thing for process controll and fast data recording all the way intothe 1980s.

Comment: Thanks! I asked because you wrote in your answer that drums were used *for RAM* *well past 1970*.

Comment: @MichaelGraf We're deep in the swamp of arbitrary definitions, aren't we? :)) I often come back to a point were I see that IBM's early concept of all storage being simply different levels of the same separated not by usage but access time.

Comment: Can you recall the name of the TROS-like system? That sounds very attractive.

Comment: re the question of whether drums are RAM or not - I think the crucial aspect is whether the CPU hardware can execute instruction off the drum, or whether a program running on the CPU has to copy off the drum to other storage from which the CPU can execute it.

Comment: Certainly drums, and their close cousins the fixed-head disks, were in use into the 1980s, but not I think as primary memory. I used a PDP-11/74 which had important tasks running from a fixed-head RS04 in the interest of performance.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two "random access, read-only memory" solutions as an example on how those were used on early computers. Both map into the address space of the CPU, and are intended to use for bootstrap programs, that load the core memory with the actual program (that one would today have in ROM).

That worked because core memory retains its contents even after power loss, so you can basically use it as a sort of ROM. It only needs to be loaded once, or re-loaded in case it gets overwritten, or has a bit-flip or similar.

The CDC series (and the Cray, too, I think) had a **deadstart panel**. [Here](http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/6600DeadStartPanel-.jpg) is a picture of the deadstart panel of a CDC 6600, and [this link](http://www.couperus.org/Albums/Bayview/Deadstart.htm) has a pictore of a more fancy one, with a description. It was essentially a set of 12 x 12 switches (so, 144 bits), and would contain the bootstrap program for a peripheral processor (PP), which then would first initialize itself from some other kind of storage, and then the main CPU.

The PDP-8/E had a **MI8-E Bootstrap Loader** card. I haven't been able to find a full picture, but [this link](http://avitech.com.au/?page_id=3204) has some close-ups. It's essentially 32 words of 12 bits (344 bits in total) hard-coded with diodes, with different variants for different bootstrap programs for different devices. You could set the start and load address with wires on the cards.

I have not found any prices for those, but from the low number of bits, you can see that it was not economical to attempt any kind of "ROM". The [PDP-8 price list](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp8/pdp8/F-82_PDP-8_Price_List_Aug67.pdf) from 1967 lists 4 kWords (with 12 bits) of core memory at around $8000 dollars. While it was technically possible to make core rope memory at the same density, I'd would have expected it to be much more expensive, as it was no longer regular, and each bit would have to be painstakingly programmed and checked manually.

Comment: That CDC deadstart panel is really cool.

Comment: Out of interest, a planned project of mine is to design & build a useful 8-bit system *without using an existing, working computer* -- this means I can't use EPROMs/Flash/any other programmable ROM solution as I will have nothing to program it with.  My current plan is to use something similar to the MI8-E, but designed with standard logic ICs: 2x 74LS138s to decode 16 addresses, diodes to pull down an internal data bus from the outputs, and a 74LS244 to drive that onto the CPU data bus if the full address decode is correct. I believe this design would have been viable & fairly cheap in 1970.

Comment: @occipita: this sounds like you should ask a separate question for that, but the standard approach is to include a front panel with switches and a bit of logic so you can directly enter values into the RAM. That's e.g. how it worked on the PDP-8, and many other minis, early micros (Altair), and even early mainframes. No diodes to simulate ROM needed, just operator time to enter the initial program.

Comment: @dirkt: The amount of ROM necessary to handle an initial program load from a simple mechanical medium (e.g. tape) would be relatively slight--probably 32 bytes or less for many systems.  Having a system that can be powered up automatically would be an advantage for many purposes.

Comment: @occipita: I still have issues of a magazine, of 43 years ago where such a set up is built around a Z80. But it is in Dutch.

Comment: @supercat yes, having an initial program load without having to do the entering is definitely useful, which is why I wrote the above answer in the first place ... but it's already on the "luxury" side. The basic variant is to have a front panel, because (a) it's more flexible, and (b) it doubles as a debugging aid. So if you want "cheap", just do the front panel.

Comment: @occipita: You may want to look into the [load mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_1802#DMA_and_load_mode) of the RCA 1802 processor.  It is an elegant way to implement front-panel loading of memory.  Also described [here](http://www.ittybittycomputers.com/IttyBitty/ShortCor.htm#chapter2).

Comment: @dirkt I originally planned that, but felt in the end that if you want a good front panel (ie one that allows you to correct mistakes and uses a keypad rather than switches) it gets quite complex, but adding a hex keypad as an IO device that generates wait states is easier, and a simple program to use it should fit in 16 or at worst 32 bytes on a Z80.

Comment: @occipita I really think now this deserves its own question, but the beauty of a front panel really is that it's very cheap, easy to use, it's not difficult to make corrections, and it does double as a debugging help - all of which is much more difficult with a hex keyboard, and processor support. If you've never used a front panel, do give it a try.

Comment: @dirkt: A front panel that stuffed instructions into a region of address space could offer some functions that would otherwise be awkward, especially on the 1802.  If one had a 74373 or equivalent wired with feedback resistors to itself, along with buttons to drive bits high and low, and a transceiver to interface to the bus, being able to stuff the sequence "ldr 1 / ldr 0 / str 1", "glo 1 / ldr 0 / plo 1", "glo 1 / ldr 0 / phi 1", glo 1 / ldi 0 / inc 1", or "glo 1 / ldi 0 / dec 1", or "glo 1 / ldi 0 / sep 1",...

Comment: ...with data bus copied to the button/light latches during the second cycle of the first instruction, and fetched from them during the second, would make it easy for a user to set or clear address bits, or individual bits at addresses, and increment/decrement addresses or goto the specified address.

Comment: @DrSheldon: The lack of a load mode in other family members discouraged their use as upgrades to the 1802, but one wouldn't need a whole lot of circuitry to implement a boot loader as functional as the built-in one on the 1802, and adding a little more could make something even more functional, using a loop of the form "op 1 / ldm 0 / op 1 / bra 0", where the first operation is either "ldm", "glo", or "ghi", and the second is "stm", "spl", "sph", "inc", "dec", or "sep", and hardware used the processor state to copy the data bus to an I/O register during the second cycle at addresses 0-1.

Comment: The read-only bootstrap memory on early-ish PDP-11s was often a photocopy of the 14-word absolute loader from the pocket programming card, taped to the front of the cabinet. It was transferred to core by programmer eyes and fingers.

Comment: @dirkt diode ROMs - the PDP-11 Unibus version was the [M792](https://www.cca.org/blog/20120222-Diode-Matrix.shtml) diode ROM. You could buy them fully-populated, programmable with wire cutters (and a soldering iron to edit your program), or else pre-programmed with particular boot logic. Capacity was 32 words x 16 bits = 256 bits.  Probably not a contender for low cost as per the question, though.  As mentioned by others, who needs ROM in kilobit quantities?  (Note: that M792 image is on a web site owned by some beardy guy called "Dave".  It is not me!)

Comment: @another-dave: I wonder whether it would have been practical to build a cam-operated contraption to enter the initial program on a PDP-11, Altair, or other such machine, either using the normal switches or a secondary set of switches that might be more conveniently designed for cam operation?  I would think a device using a drum and roller switches could allow someone to feed in a 14-byte boot loader in under two seconds by simply turning a crank once.

Comment: @supercat - [This groundbreaking technology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ34RDn34Ws) could surely be adapted.

Comment: @another-dave: I was actually proposing the idea somewhat seriously.  An I/O device that represents bits using pegs placed in a drum might not be practical for storing very much data, or any data that would be likely to change, but hardware to automatically run a program stored on such a device may be much simpler than would be needed to automatically run programs from other devices which would otherwise be more practical for many purposes.

Comment: For PDP-11 console switches, you need to be able to flip keys up and down, so a simple rotating drum will not suffice.  Something more like a musical box arrangement might work, with push-to-make release-to-break switches. I can't see this being cost-effective, though once you've wired it in.  Surely a couple of hundred diodes (14 words, not bytes, in the absolute loader) did not cost that much?

Answer (score 2):

[EDSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDSAC) (operational in 1949) had read-only memory to hold its [Initial Orders](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1950RSPSA.202..573W/abstract).  The Initial Orders were wired on to uniselectors, and when running, allowed the easy (!) loading of other programs from paper tape.  That is, they provided the services of a boot ROM, with some aspects of an assembler built it.

Since this was post-war Britain, the uniselectors were almost certainly surplus equipment, and therefore cheap.

The capacity was around 50 words; see [this link](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Emark/edsac.html) for a listing of "Initial Orders 2".  There's a picture of the uniselectors on a modern reconstruction of EDSAC [here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/national-museum-of-computing-opens-edsac-display-recreating-1949s-top-computer/).

Comment: This sounds like it what I was looking for when I asked  https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/did-any-computers-use-automatically-operated-mechanical-storage-as-electronicall and it might be good to add the information there as well.

Comment: @supercat - before I joined!   but you're right it would have answered your question.  I'll add something.  Somewhere I ran across a description of how the program was actually encoded on the uniselectors; it would be nice if I could find it again!

Answer (score 1):

The Apollo Guidance Computer used Core Rope memory.  The read-only instructions were woven into the rope (in one story, by canonical little-old-ladies)

Before that, computers used diode matrix memory, and switched relay selection of plugboard settings, both of which were fixed access time read-only data stores.

Comment: You can still make your own diode matrix memory (no vacuum tube logic required): https://hackaday.com/2013/10/18/making-a-diode-matrix-rom/

Comment: I would think diode matrix memory could be cheaper than rope memory, but physically heavier.  Not a problem for most terrestrial computing applications, but LEM "dry weight" was far more expensive than gold.